# Переход на другое Activity через 5 секунд

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Хочу в приложении сделать что-то вроде заставки.
Пользователь заходит в приложение, ему открывается первая Activity, и через 5 секунд бросает на другое.

Делаю так:

```
int ii = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


setContentView(R.layout.fon);

    try {

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        ii = 5;

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    System.out.println(ii);

    if (ii == 5) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Web.class); 
    startActivity(intent2);
    }

}
```

И получается в результате следующее: Пользователь заходит в приложение, ему видно первое Activity и через 5 секунд открывается другое активити. 
Но проблема в том что на первом активити ему не видно экрана, то есть не работает `setContentView(R.layout.fon);`

Что я делаю не так?
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы приостановили главный поток строкой

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

Так у вас вообще должно было вылететь по `ANR`

Останавливать главный поток не надо. Это плохая практика. Вам надо сделать иначе - запустить отложенную задачу один из множества способов, например, так:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
             TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
             Intent intent2 = new Intent(ТУТ_ИМЯ_КЛАССА_АКТИВИТИ.this, Web.class); 
startActivity(intent2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Запускаете в `onCreate()`

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);//Ставите сколько сек, 1000 = 1с.
```